# return a sorted list of int

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I know there are multiple other threads on this but I can't wrap my head around why it

```
public int[] practice_5(List<int> items)
{
    if (items == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        List<int> items_sorted = items.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
        return items_sorted;
    }
}
```

So I have sorted the list of items correctly. I'm assuming but no matter what workaround I try, it won't return it because it can't convert type `List<int>` to `int[]`?

Do I have to convert the variable `items_sorted` before returning?

Comment: use ToArray or change return type of method to List. if you want Array please remove ToList call. that will only make a redundant copy. so you should do `return items.OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();`

Comment: Just use toarray in the end

Comment: You define your return parameter as an array, and then try to return a `List`. Why would you expect that to work? You might want to consider `IEnumerable<int>` as your return type if for some reason you want to be able to return an array as well as a list.

Comment: Thanks everyone, so it seems I didn't read completely and understand what the .ToList() part did. I didn't know there was an equivalent for an array. Thank you for explaining that part of my code. I am a beginning and I'm learning the best I can!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
public int[] practice_5(List<int> items)
{

    if (items == null)
    {
       return null;
    }
    else
    {
       return items.OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();
    }
}
```

or if you want a full refactor, and assuming C# 6.0 or higher.

```
public int[] practice_5(List<int> items)
{
    return items?.OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was it. I now understand the difference between an array and list.

Comment: A bit cleaner is without the else